# Interpreting a very high exp(b) in negative binomial regression

Tags: regression, interpretation, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm doing a negative binomial regression with 5 continuous predictors and have run into a problem with output interpretation. That is, one of the variables has a much larger B and exp(b) than the others.

[image: Parameter estimates]

I have suspicions that it depends on the metric used in the variables (i.e., the problematic predictor has values less than 1 (e.g., 0,7, 0,8 etc.) while the rest of the predictors have values far larger than 1). Could it be the case? If yes, would it be better to first transform the variable/all the variables?
If not - how to report/interpret this data?